# Python 2.7 sort function that sets a sequence number property

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I want to be able to sort a list of objects (let's say dictionaries for now), but instead of re-arranging their locations in a list, I'd like to set a property on each one to an integer value that represents it's place in the sequence.

For example, suppose I have a list like this:

```
mylist = [
  {
    'date': '2018-07-02',
    'sequence': null
  },

  {
    'date': '2015-01-03',
    'sequence': null
  },
  {
    'date': '2017-05-12',
    'sequence': null
  },
  ...
]
```

I'd like to have a function that looks like:

```
assign_sequence(my_list, key='date', sequence_property='sequence')
```

And have it output:

```
[
  {
    'date': '2018-07-02',
    'sequence': 3
  },    
  {
    'date': '2015-01-03',
    'sequence': 1
  },
  {
    'date': '2017-05-12',
    'sequence': 2
  },
  ...
]
```

The reason is that the data is ultimately for a legacy system that expects the sequence number and can't work without it.

Of course I can just sort them in the traditional way, and then iterate over them again with enumerate() and assign the index. But I was just wondering if there's a more efficient or more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "argsort". I would do it just how you called the "traditional way", for what it's worth. The date strings will sort correctly using lexicographical order, assuming they are all in `%Y-%m%-%d` format.

```
>>> null = None
>>> mylist = [
...   {
...     'date': '2018-07-02',
...     'sequence': null
...   },
... 
...   {
...     'date': '2015-01-03',
...     'sequence': null
...   },
...   {
...     'date': '2017-05-12',
...     'sequence': null
...   },
... ]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> for i, d in enumerate(sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter('date')), start=1):
...     d['sequence'] = i  # mutate dicts in place
...     
>>> mylist
[{'date': '2018-07-02', 'sequence': 3},
 {'date': '2015-01-03', 'sequence': 1},
 {'date': '2017-05-12', 'sequence': 2}]
```

[`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) might give you a speedup if you have huge data and performance is critical, but don't bother otherwise.